# How can I feed a "defaults write" from a file?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

Right now, I can populate a defaults-write key with an array elements as follows:

```
 defaults write mydomain mykey -array A B C D
```

I wonder how can I do the same where the elements are read from a file, something along these lines:
`defaults write mydomain mykey -array < filename`

Comment: The simple answer is `defaults write mydomain mykey -array $(cat filename)`, but that won't work if the items contain any funny characters (spaces, anything that looks like a filename wildcards) or include syntax (quotes, escapes, etc). What format is the file in?

Comment: @GordonDavisson how do you think the file would need to be formatted to load defaults write with a dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: With this approach it'd need to be `key1 value1 key2 value2 ...` -- but this seems really fragile. I don't think I'd recommend trying to load a dictionary directly from a file.

Comment: so far It works alright for my needs. I put "keyx valuex" each on a separate line and they are being loaded correctly. thanks